# Nav Bar button loading random view before loading appropriate view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, back

I have a back button on my answer view controller (a view controller that displays answers) if the user hits the back button I created it switches to a view that has the title of "Back" and just an empty tableview, before switching back to my main view of where all the questions to be answered are displayed. Why is this happening? Its a very brief thing, but definitely noticeable!

```
 UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 48)];
navBar.delegate = self;
UINavigationItem *backItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"];
[navBar pushNavigationItem:backItem animated:NO];

UINavigationItem *topItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Question"];
[navBar pushNavigationItem:topItem animated:NO];
topItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

[self.view addSubview:navBar];


- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{

   ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
   controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
   [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
   return true;
}

- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{

   ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
   controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
   [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

[image: Picture of view with back button]
[image: Picture of problem that is occurring]

Comment: Why are you managing the nav bar yourself rather than using a nav controller? You're creating a nav item with a title of "Back"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating your own `UINavigationBar` and `UINavigationItem` instances and you probably shouldn't be. The situation you describe is exactly what a `UINavigationController` is for. When using a `UINavigationController` it creates the `UINavigationBar` and each `UIViewController` that you show on screen (push into the navigation controller) has its own `UINavigationItem` (with the title taken from the `title` of the view controller).

The reason you get an empty 'view' titled "Back" is that you're creating it:

```
UINavigationItem *backItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"];
[navBar pushNavigationItem:backItem animated:NO];
```

Dispense with all of this, create a `UINavigationController` and make your question view controller it's root view controller, then add the navigation controller to the screen. Then when a question is answered, push the answer view controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:answerViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Good answer, I just wrote the same thing but you beat me to it.